# How to implement the relationship between wpf Usercontrol and Data Object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` and a Data Object which I want to bind them together so The WPF UserControl always presents the data in the object:

```
public partial class PersonRectangle : UserControl
{
    public PersonRectangle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string fname;
    public string lname;
    public Person()
    {

    }
}
```

What is the best way to wire any Person to the associated wpf View? Should I add a property of type `Person` to the partial class `PersonRectangle`? How should I do this considering MVVM paradigms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataContext property from UserControl is the key to mvvm implementation, Person is your model and should not be exposed directly to View but through ViewModel object.

```
public class PersonViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        /*You could initialize Person from data store or create new here but not necessary. 
        It depends on your requierements*/
        Person = new Person(); 
    }

    private Person person;
    public Person Person{ 
        get {return person;}
        set { 
            if ( person != value){ 
                person = value;
                OnPropertyChanged()
            }
        }
    }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

Then in your View (UserControl):

```
public partial class PersonRectangle : UserControl
{
    public PersonRectangle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PersonViewModel();
    }
}
```

You already set DataContext so you the can bind your view controls to Person properties, note the use of Person property from ViewModel here:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Person.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

My final words would be to suggest you to use an MVVM framework like [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) or [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/)

> EDIT:

You should consider to expose Person data as properties and not as public variables as you have now.